# Bash: How to store a specific line of CLI output into a file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, output

1. Let's assume I receive the following output after executing a bash script in CLI (so this text will be displayed in terminal):

   ```
   POST https://mycompany.com/
   COOKIE='BLABLABLABLABLA'
   HOST='ANYIPADDRESS'
   FINGERPRINT='sha256:BLABLABLABLA'
   ```

   How can I store the content of `COOKIE` (only the text between `'` and `'`) into a separate file?

---

2. Furthermore, the mentioned text should be pasted into this external file at a specific position.

   The already existing file content looks like that:

   ```
   [global]
   Name = Name of VPN connection

   [provider_openconnect]
   Type = OpenConnect
   Name = Name of VPN connection
   Host = IP-address
   Domain = Domain name
   OpenConnect.Cookie = >>>INSERT CONTENT OF THE COOKIE HERE<<<
   OpenConnect.ServerCert = sha256:BLABLABLABLA
   ```

   How is that possible?

Comment: I assume you're able to re-run the script in order to capture the output again? In other words, you're not trying to "scrape the screen" for that already-passed output?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Exactly, I can re-run the script as often as I want. The cookie will change every time though, but this does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These types of thing are not generic in nature, but specific though approach is generic

---

I am assuming, you want to replace `OpenConnect.Cookie =` line with `OpenConnect.Cookie = BLABLABLABLABLA`

So, to first create required string , you can use

```
sed -i  "s/^OpenConnect.Cookie =.*$/$( command_giving_output  | grep 'COOKIE=' | sed "s/COOKIE='//; s/'//g; s/^/OpenConnect.Cookie = /")/" external_filename
```

Here I am using command substitution to first create required string

```
command_giving_output  | grep 'COOKIE=' | sed "s/COOKIE='//; s/'//g; s/^/OpenConnect.Cookie = /"
```

and then substituting required line by this required string

```
sed -i  "s/^OpenConnect.Cookie =.*$/output from above command substitution /" external_filename
```

Comment: GNU grep can do [lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247812/how-to-use-grep-to-get-anything-just-after-name) which saves you the nested `sed`.

Comment: It is pretty difficult to decide which one of all those great answers deserves the "Answer"-flag. I have chosen the answer with the most upvotes - I hope that is okay for you? Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can read the cookie using a combination of bash's read and `grep`:

```
IFS="'" read -r _ cookie _ < <(some-command | grep '^COOKIE')
```

This uses process substitution to feed the output of `some-command | grep '^COOKIE')` to `read`. With `IFS="='"`, we split the input on `'`, discarding the first element of the split (`COOKIE=`) (and any remaining text after the closing quote), while saving the second in the `cookie` variable.

Then we can use `sed` to replace the text:

```
sed -i 's/>>>INSERT CONTENT OF THE COOKIE HERE<<</'"$cookie"'/' some-file
```

This depends on the cookie text not containing special characters like `&`, though.

Comment: I suggest you `read -r _ cookie _` to capture any garbage that might follow the 2nd single quote.

Comment: It is pretty difficult to decide which one of all those great answers deserves the "Answer"-flag. I have chosen the answer with the most upvotes - I hope that is okay for you? Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
. <(command | grep "^COOKIE=")
sed -i "s/\(OpenConnect.Cookie\)\s*=.*/\1 = ""$COOKIE""/" file
```

Where:

- `file` is the existing file with contents as described in the question.
- `command` is the your command that prints the text to the terminal.
- `grep "^COOKIE="` searches for a line starting with `COOKIE=`
- and the dot in the beginning of the command "sources" the output. This means that the output is interpreted as shell code. Thus the variable `$COOKIE` is set in the current shell.
- The `sed` command then replaces the line in the destination file with the contents of the variable `$COOKIE`.

Comment: It is pretty difficult to decide which one of all those great answers deserves the "Answer"-flag. I have chosen the answer with the most upvotes - I hope that is okay for you? Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
sed -f <(CLI command | sed -n '/COOKIE=\o047/{s//\/OpenConnect.Cookie =\/ s\/= \.*$\/= /; s/.$/\//p;}') file
[global]
Name = Name of VPN connection

[provider_openconnect]
Type = OpenConnect
Name = Name of VPN connection
Host = IP-address
Domain = Domain name
OpenConnect.Cookie = BLABLABLABLABLA
OpenConnect.ServerCert = sha256:BLABLABLABLA
```

It creates a "`sed` script file" on the fly by extracting / massageing the relevant data from your CLI command, and executes this script file using "process substitution" in a second `sed` call.

Comment: It is pretty difficult to decide which one of all those great answers deserves the "Answer"-flag. I have chosen the answer with the most upvotes - I hope that is okay for you? Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on [@MSalters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/24083/msalters)'s comment. The shell used is Bash.

```
prompt% COOKIE=$(./mycmd | grep -Po "(?<=COOKIE=)'[[:alnum:]]+'" | tr -d \')
prompt% echo "$COOKIE" >/tmp/cookie
prompt% sed -i "s:\(OpenConnect.Cookie =\).*:\1 $COOKIE:" file
```

**Alternative solution (using GNU `expr`)**

This solution works if there is only one matching result.

```
prompt% COOKIE=$(expr "$(./mycmd | grep COOKIE)" : "COOKIE='\([[:alnum:]]\+\)'[[:space:]]*")
prompt% echo "$COOKIE" >/tmp/file
prompt% sed -i "s:\(OpenConnect.Cookie =\).*:\1 $COOKIE:" file
```

Comment: It is pretty difficult to decide which one of all those great answers deserves the "Answer"-flag. I have chosen the answer with the most upvotes - I hope that is okay for you? Thank you very much for your help!!!